# Variable alias in a for cycle with Jinja2

Tags: variables, jinja2, alias

I have this code inside my html:

```
{% for macchine in range(20) %}
    {% set macchina_usata = 'M'+ macchine|string  %}
    {{ data['macchina_usata'] }}
    {% if data['macchina_usata'] is defined %}

    do something..

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

before it was without the for cycle, I just had to check if a variable is defined and I got the result, but now I want to put it in a Cycle for because I have to check 20 or more variables.

The variables that I got from the previous html are like `M1, M2, M3, ... M20` then I thought that was a good idea to create a varible `macchina_usata` composed by `M`+ the int `macchine` converted in a `string`, but when I try to print it nothing happen, so, i guess that I'm using the Alias in a wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the literal string `'macchina_usata'` as an index for `data`. You should instead use variable `macchina_usata`, without the quotes:

```
{{ data[macchina_usata] }}
{% if data[macchina_usata] is defined %}
```